# How to put a regex filter in a where clause in bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

How do I add to the where clause of a sql select statement to match a particular regex.

I have a table with phone numbers.  The phone numbers are 10 digits long.  The data is dirty, so I want to not select records that are not in this format.  like this:

```
select * from Phones where Phones like `RegExp("^\\d{9}$")`;  <-- this doesn't work
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL - use below (assuming your regexp itself is correct)

```
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(Phones, r'^\d{10}$')
```

above will filter out any row where Phone is not 10 digits string